# Error in locating a local minimum using quadratic interpolation

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods

I have 3 data points that are spaced equally apart.  For example, I have the data points $(-h,y_n)$, $(0,y_0)$, and $(h,y_p)$, where $y_0 < y_n$ and $y_0<y_p$.  From these, a quadratic interpolating polynomial is found that fits all 3 data points, and then the location of the local minimum is analytically determined.

$y = ax^2 + bx + c$, $x_{min} = -\frac{b}{2a}$.

Now the underlying function is not actually quadratic, but it is smooth.  How do I estimate the error in $x_{min}$  (I don't care about the corresponding error in $y$).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can. First of all, there need not to be only one local minimum, but arbitrarily many.

Even ignoring this, smooth functions can do pretty much anything. Go up and down pretty quicly, oscillate, etc.

So your local minimum can be any point in the range $(-h, h)$.

If you take $x_{min} = 0$ then the error is bound by $h$, but that does not make much sense, does it?

Comment: Smooth functions can do anything, but if the function is describable by some higher order Taylor series expansion, the error in locating the minimum is bounded by some function of the Taylor series coefficients.  In any case, I _think_ I've figured it out.

Comment: @wrjohns And how? Because even analytical functions can be pretty much anything. Anyhow post your solution as an answer to your question, so the community can benefit from it eventually.